# MATLAB sort and column number

Tags: matlab, logic

I need to know the original column numbers of an row vector sorted in descending order. Its probably a simple question to you, but Im not very good at coding.Thanks.

Comment: If I understood correctly your question it's not possible, unless you store somewhere else the original position of each element. If the vector contains numbers that would be equivalent of copying the original array.

Comment: Ok could you tell me how to do this? I have an array of 10 numbers : [2 5 1 10 4 100 90 34 5 0]. I want to sort this in the descending order and then I want an array with their original positions in the respective positions. Like answer for this is : [6 7 8 4 2 9 5 1 3 10]. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
 [sorted, indexes] = sort(YOUR_VECTOR, 'descend');
```

this way, `sorted` will be the sorted vector, and `indexes` will contain the original position of this elements as ilustrated in http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html

Comment: I believe you should pass 'descend' instead of 'descending'